# How is GOMAXPROCS determined on different platforms and inside containers?

Tags: docker, go, cgroups

I am curious how does Go runtime determine `runtime.NumCPU()` (count of CPUs) on various platforms with wildly different characteristics like Linux, macOS and Windows?

For example on Linux: I'm curious if it uses sysfs (/sys) to look at paths like `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us` to determine how many CPUs exist, or  procfs (`/proc/cpuinfo`) (this will be the wrong value in a container environment where container may have access to fewer CPUs than the host CPU count exposed in this file).

Similarly on macOS, how is this value determined?

I know some applications like JVM relies on cgroups memory info exposed on  /sys to set their internal heap size etc.

Comment: Each OS is different. If you're interested in how it's actually done, wouldn't that be answered simply by looking at the source that sets the cpu count? It's not worth linking and copying the current source, since that changes over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go `GOMAXPROCS` is a function of the number of CPUs. The number of CPUs is a function of the processor architecture: 386, amd64, arm, arm64, mips64, ppc64, s390, etc, The operating system provides an interface to the hardware: Linux, OpenBSD, Mac OS, etc. On Linux, we have `SYS_sched_getaffinity`.

See [Go source code](https://go.googlesource.com/go) in `src/runtime`.

See Linux documentation command `man sched_getaffinity`.

Answer (score 3):

The number of CPUs is evaluated at running time, and it is OS dependent. If you take a look inside the Go runtime package, you will see many files with 
postfixes related to OS and architecture names:

- [FreeBSD](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_freebsd.go)
- [Darwin](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_darwin.go)
- [Plan9](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_plan9.go)
- [OpenBSD](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_openbsd.go)
- [Linux](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_linux.go)
- [Google Native
  Client](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_nacl.go)
- [Windows](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_windows.go)
- [NetBSD](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_netbsd.go)
- [Solaris](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os3_solaris.go)
- [DragonFly
  BSD](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_dragonfly.go)

When a Go program is built, only the right runtime file that corresponds to the current OS and architecture is included. The number of CPUs will then be evaluated by the function `getncpu`.

Comment: I don’t get the point of the “finding the file” section. The build constraints are in the filename, so why go through all that trouble to confirm what the toolchain is documented to do?

Comment: @JimB I agree, it was cumbersome and with a lot of unnecessary information, thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer - less is more :D.

Comment: I was hoping the answer can link to some of the implementations directly or explain them. The reason I asked this is so that there’s some explanation on the internet and not everyone has to dive into the runtime pkg source.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google: then you need to ask a specific question about what you don't understand. We can't go through and explain every single aspect of the syscalls. Do you want a call by call explanation of the linux `sched_getaffinity` assembly? Do you want to know what `sysctl` is? Do you want to know how the windows loader sets up the `_GetProcessAffinityMask` syscall? They're all very different.

Comment: Yes this is my bad, I was asking for the actual syscalls or other methods Go use to find numprocs.